# How to retrieve the current post's generated featured image size?

Tags: functions, customization, post-thumbnails

Is there any way to retrieve the current post's generated featured image size, width and height.

For example if any post's featured image set is of size 540 x 400, although it should be of 550 px x 550 px (according to the thumbnail size registered, but it was not able to generate it due low size).

How to retrieve the  current post's featured image size to store $width = 540 & $height = 400 in the current example.

Please help me to find a way!
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), which gives precisely data you need (URL and dimensions). Which help to figure out your problem.

sample code

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 10 );
if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

The return section gives keys, but the function just returns indexes as.

```
array{
    [0] => url,
    [1] => width,
    [2] => height,
    [3] => is_intermediate (boolean)
}
```

We should make it clearer what is returned by this function. And some description or a link to explain is_intermediate.

Comment: Can you please show me the way to do it, i am confused.
It will help a lot thank you!